# What would be the equivalent of SQL [IN] statement for C# Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am in this scenario. I have two lists of two different object types, which both have a shared property value. Let's say that it is `invoiceID`.

In SQL, if I want to grab all records from `table_A` given that it has column `invoiceID` value match with any `invoiceId` inside `table_B`, I would probably do something like this.

```
Select *
From table_A
where invoiceID in ( select invoiceId from table_B)
```

What would be the equivalent LINQ or Lambda expression in C# for this scenario?

I am used to search for elements in the list using a single value such as:

```
var result = list_A.Where(x=>x.InvoiceID = someInvoiceID)
```

or `.contains()` instead.

However, this could cover only a single `invoiceID` value.

I guess, I could run the loop for each `invoiceID` on `list_B` and then store the result in another list, but I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't the question from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918217/linq-lambda-equivalent-of-sql-in) intends for the case where movieratings is already a list of values? My issue is that I would have movieratings inside Movies object. Hence, I can't do .Where(x=>Movies.Contains(x.Value)) nor .Where(x=>Movies.MovieRatings.Contains(x.value)), where Movies is a list<Movie>().. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
var someInvoiceList = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
var result = list_A.Where(x => someInvoiceList.Contains(x.InvoiceID));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. How would this play out if instead of having someInvoiceList as a data array, we have someObjectList, where invoice is a property of the objects in this list?

Comment: Ah silly me, I could have just make an array or list of invoices from the list of ObjectB first, then follow the steps from above.

Thank you!

Comment: Something like this: var list = new List<Invorce>(); var someInvoiceList = list.Select(x=>x.id)